# objectAtIndex is used twice in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been working through the following [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/), and came across this code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfFirstname], [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfLastname]];
```

Here is the part I dont understand:

```
[[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfFirstname]
```

objectAtIndex is used twice here. I dont understand what is going on here. 
I tried to study how Arrays work,which I understand. But this line stumped me

Comment: An array within an array.

Comment: You have taken array in array so that two times objectAtIndex used

Comment: i only see one array: self.arrPeopleInfo

Comment: if you put a breakpoint and view in debugger you can see there are 2 arrays. arrPeopleInfo has multiple arrays in that each array holds 3 objects like firstname,lastname and age. that's why in the tutorial index is used twice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

arrPeopleInfo is a multidimensional array. (Array in an array. Every object of the normal array, itselve is an array.)

So you have for example:

```
multidimensionalArray:
1  - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
2  - 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3
3  - 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2
4  - 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3
5  - 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4
6  - 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

[multidimensionalArray objectAtIndex:1] = 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3

[[multidimensionalArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:2] = 4

Comment: I would really like a comment, if I get a minus 1. My answer is valid and at least then I know what to improve next time..

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's quite straight forward, first pick an object from `arrPeopleInfo` and then pick another object from the *resulting* array. You could break this in to two steps in order to understand it better:

```
// The variable names (and the NSString type) are speculative here 
NSArray *person = [self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *name  = [person objectAtIndex:indexOfFirstname];

// and to complete your example...
NSString *lastName = [person objectAtIndex:indexOfLastname];
```

which finally results to:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", name, lastName];
```

---

PS. Another way to illustrate access on nested arrays would be something like this (a rather silly example, but you get the idea...):

```
NSArray *a  = @[ @[@"a", @"b"], @[@"c", @"d"] ]; // An array with 2 arrays
NSString *b = a[0][1]; // Get the object at 0 [a,b] then the object at 1 (b)
NSLog(@"%@", b); // Prints b
```

Comment: in your example, you did not use objectAtIndex twice.

Answer (score 1):

Your array must be something like this:

```
(
   (
      "firstname 1",
      "lastname 1"
   ),
   (
      "firstname 2",
      "lastname 2"
   ),
   (
      "firstname 3",
      "lastname 3"
   ),
   (
      "firstname 4",
      "lastname 4"
   )
)
```

Now lets discuss about `[[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfFirstname]`.

This line of code contains two statements, we can saperate this like:

```
NSArray * personArray = [self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString * fName = [personArray objectAtIndex:indexOfFirstname];
```

if `indexPath.row` is 2 `personArray` will give you following array, which is 3rd object of `self.arrPeopleInfo`:

```
   (
      "firstname 3",
      "lastname 3"
   )
```

Now second statement : `indexOfFirstname` will be 0(zero). So `fName` will be `firstname 3` which is first object of `personArray`.

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an Array inside the array. It is very confusing way to program in Objective-C but pretty normal in C
i would use an NSDictionary inside the array instead.